# Do spaces/comments slow Javascript down?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering, do whitespaces and comments slow down JavaScript? I'm doing a brute force attack which takes some time (30 seconds). Removing whitespaces does not show a significant growth in speed, but I think the browser just does have to parse more.

So, is it of any use to remove unnecessary whitespaces and comments to speed the whole up?

Comment: Ideally, javascript should be compressed on production environments. So the answer is yes, it is of use.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it will not be on a website nor fetched very often; in fact, I just need to run certain algorithms just a few times  to calculate for myself. So bandwidth is not really what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Sergey: this is not true. Comments and whitespace had negligible effect on performance even _before_ modern browsers with JIT compiler built-in.

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone know of a extremely useful tool for minifying - the Google Closure Compiler: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People usually use minimizers to reduce the SIZE of the script, to improve download speed, rather than to make any difference in speed of parsing the script.

Whitespace and comments will have little effect in how long it takes a browser to execute, as the parser needs to check if it is whitespace, or a comment, but in reality this will be so minute with current computing power, it would be impossible to notice any impact.

SIZE however is still important even with the large bandwidth available in our broadband world.

Comment: I see, so I'll keep it then. Minifying every time will take much more time in the end, and I'm not publishing my algorithms online anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to reduce the SIZE of a script?  Do you mean the number of characters?

Comment: yes, Size == bytes of data, so can roughly equate to number of characters.

Comment: You need to minimize it only in production servers. So running a script on server side to minimize your server files every time while keeping your developer files induct, is a good option. My little view on the point.

Answer (score 4):

Whitespaces and comments increase the size of the JavaScript file, which slows down the actual downloading of the file from the server - *minification* is the process of stripping unnecessary characters from a JavaScript file to make it smaller and easier to download.

However, since you mention a brute force attack, the bottleneck is probably *not* the download. Try using a profiler to find what slows you down.

Answer (score 4):

There is always a point in minifying, combining and gzipping your assets, to ease server load.

- Minifying is the act you refer to, of stripping away unnecessary whitespace and comments, to make the download speed smaller.
- Combining will most likely show an even greater increase in page rendering speed; it is the act of merging all your javascript files into one, and all your css files into one (it can also be done for most images, but that taks requires some more work). This is done to reduce the amount of requests the browser has to make towards your server, to be able to display the page.
- GZipping is the act of further compressing the data, in a zipped format, to the browsers that indicate that they'll accept such data. This further reduces size, but adds some extra work load at both ends. You're likely to see a net gain from it.

Depending on what environment you're working in, there are different components that'll help you with this, that usually covers all of the above in one go.

The time your code takes to download from the server has a direct effect on how long the page takes to render. JavaScript is blocking, meaning that a JS block will prevent any furhter rendering, until the block has executed entirely. As such, where you put your javascript files (i.e. in which point in the rendering process they'll be requested), how many requests it takes for it to be completely downloaded, and how much data there is to download, will have an impact on your page load, as it appears to the user.

Once the browser has parsed your code, be it javascript, css or html, it'll have created internal representations of the part it needs to keep remembering, and the actual formatting will no longer affect it.

Comment: Thanks, you've taught me some very useful things here. However, my case does not have anything to do with servers, as I'm running it locally. I'll keep this in mind in the future, it is really helpful.

Comment: Yes, for local deployments you may safely disregard this. If you'll ever end up doing something like this, you'll want to find a tool that automates it for you. Beware, when you start using this in production, you'll also want to use it locally. Not because of local speed benefits, but because you want your development environment to match your production environment as closely as possible. That's a different question entirely, tho :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think whitespace in js-code slows down the *execution* of it. As far as I understand a javascript interpreter strips all comments and redundant whitespace before processing. It can influence download time en thus loading time of a web page however.

Take a look [here](http://www.comanswer.com/question/do-javascript-compilers-have-its-preference-over-how-indentation-spaces-and-curly-braces-are-placed-in-the-source-code) for a bit of extra information.

Comment: If that is true, I don't think I'll have to care about it at all. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It has little to no impact on actual processing speed, however...

Smaller size => less bandwith => less costs => ??? => profit!